# What function is called when the Check in button is clicked

Tags: ribbon, check-in

Which function is called when you click on the "Check In" button of a page? I am referring to the button that opens the following modal dialog window.

[image: Check In Page]

It does not reference a page (already checked it with fiddler).

*Update*

The function that Howard specified will have the following result:

[image: Check In Page with version settings]

If you want to try it out, here is the code:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current()
var str=ctx.get_url()+"/_layouts/checkin.aspx?"+"List=Pages&FileName="+document.location;
OpenPopUpPage(str, CheckInNotifyAndRefreshPage);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you click `Check In` button, method `handleCommand` called from javascript object `SP.Ribbon.PageState.PageStateHandler` (sp.ribbon.js) with commandId = "PageStateGroupCheckin"
If you debug it, you can find that it executes this line at least:

```
return SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.showStateChangeDialog(properties['CommandValueId'], SP.Ribbon.PageState.ImportedNativeData.CommandHandlers[properties['CommandValueId']]);
```

**EDIT**
Ok, somebody down voted, I'll explain how to find this function.
First of all inspect check in button using firebug or google chrome dev tools. Check in button is a link with id `Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.Checkout.Menu.Checkout.Checkin-Menu16`. Next, go to cmdui.xml file in 14 hive. Here using search find button with id `Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.Checkout.Menu.Checkout`. You will find this menu:

```
<Menu Id="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.Checkout.Menu">
```

and button with definition:

```
<Button
  Id="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.Checkout.Menu.Checkout.Checkin"
  MenuItemId="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.Checkout.Menu.Checkout.Checkin"
  Sequence="20"
  Alt="$Resources:core,ButCheckin;"
  Command="PageStateGroupCheckin"
  CommandValueId="PageStateGroupCheckin"
  Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-104" Image16by16Left="-32"
  Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-416" Image32by32Left="-192"
  LabelText="$Resources:core,ButCheckin;"
  ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,ButCheckin;"
  ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_STT_ButCheckin_page;"
 />
```

We interested in `CommandValueId` attribute. Next go to sp.ribbon.debug.js and using search find object, which handle this particular commandid - this is `SP.Ribbon.PageState.PageStateHandler`. All commands in page component handle method `handleCommand`, setup break and click check in in browser - consider screen shot below:

[image: img]

if you step further you got to line, that I mentioned above: 
[image: img]

It means, that when you press `Check In` in the ribbon method `SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.showStateChangeDialog` fires.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Please, comment why down vote?

Comment: Valid answer to me, had enough detail even before you elaborated. +1 from me.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Now I see what I was been doing wrong.

Comment: When I try to call SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.showStateChangeDialog in SharePoint 2013 I get following error: "Unable to get property 'CommandHandlers' of undefined or null reference".

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the CheckInSingleItem function which can be found in \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\INPLVIEW.js

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this does not open the correct check in page. This opens the one with the check in versions.